# Creating a stats page in SilverStripe CMS

Tags: silverstripe

SilverStripe 2.4.7

Hi

I want to create a stats page in the CMS but I'm not entirely sure how to do this.  If it were an ordinary PHP page I would query the database, save the values to an array and display them in a table.  I need it to look similar to the other CMS pages too.

I have included my own php files for other things in the CMS so I was wondering can I do the same here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you do the tutorials? You should, it will tell you what to extend - don't forget: This is MVC and OOP, not plain old PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIthout providing more details, all I can do is point you to the [Site Reports](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/site-reports) documentation for SilverStripe 3.

This will allow you to show your DataObjects in table form, based on filters and sorting that you choose.

If the basics of SS is what you're after, start with the [tutorials](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/).

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin Smith.  It is a stats page based on a number which is saved in the database.  It's not really SS related which is why I am a little unclear on how to go about it. The best way I can describe what is happening is that a number in the DB table is incremented each time the information is accessed in a related mobile app so I want to show what is accessed most.

Comment: See the [SQLQuery](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery) docs. You should be able to access other DB tables/fields and create new SS dataobjects.